# Run setup.exe with proxy settings. Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, windows-8, proxy

Is it possible to execute a setup file with proxy settings?
Аfter starting an installation setup.exe is trying to connect to external url to download extra files, needed for installation but has no network access.

My proxy settings configured in IE and internet works properly. Also I know my credentials i.e. login\pass and proxy address and port

Comment: No such thing as `setup.exe`. Plenty of installers have this name so you have to be specific. Some may pay attention to the global proxy settings, others don't.

Comment: in my case this is mtgo client installer (Magic The Gathering Online)